# Missing font 'zplsups-Regular-t1' after Catalina update on macOS

Tags: fonts, errors, pdftex, mac

I seem to be missing some fonts since the Catalina update.

Minimal failing example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
Error at footnote number here.\footnote{Error just now.}
\end{document}
```

Output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 1
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newpx/newpxtext.sty
`newpxtext' v1.321, 2017/08/18 Text macros taking advantage of TeXGyre Pagella 
and its extensions (msharpe)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontaxes/fontaxes.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newpx/t1zpltlf.fd)
No file test.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newpx/t1zplsups.fd) [1{/usr/local
/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux)
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 0+480/600 --dpi 480 zplsups-Regular-t1
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for zplsups-Regular-t1.
mktexpk: perhaps zplsups-Regular-t1 is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
!pdfTeX error: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex (file zplsups-Regular-t1): Font zpl
sups-Regular-t1 at 480 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I've manually checked /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map and the font is indeed missing from the mapping file.
However if I locate it on my system I can find it:

```
$ locate zplsups
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/newpx/zplsups-Bold-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/newpx/zplsups-Bold-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/newpx/zplsups-Bold-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/newpx/zplsups-BoldItalic-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/newpx/zplsups-BoldItalic-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/newpx/zplsups-BoldItalic-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/newpx/zplsups-Italic-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/newpx/zplsups-Italic-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/newpx/zplsups-Italic-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/newpx/zplsups-Regular-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/newpx/zplsups-Regular-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/newpx/zplsups-Regular-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newpx/ly1zplsups.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newpx/ot1zplsups.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newpx/t1zplsups.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/t1fonts/zplsups-Bold-t1.htf
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/t1fonts/zplsups-BoldItalic-t1.htf
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/t1fonts/zplsups-Italic-t1.htf
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/t1fonts/zplsups-Regular-t1.htf
```

I tried reinstalling newpx, newtx, and tex-gyre packages via Tex-Live Utility, but it didn't change anything.

Any idea how I get that font back into my mapping file?

Comment: Catalina has nothing to do with this. The `newpx` fonts underwent a major upgrade and apparently the maintainer forgot to add the needed map entries for the `zplsups` fonts.

Comment: I filed a bug report to the package author.

Comment: Ah, it was just a timing coincidence then. Thanks for the workaround :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distributed `newpx.map` file misses the entries for the `zplsups` family of fonts, which is a bug in the last upgrade of the `newpx` suite.

For the time being, until the bug is fixed, you can use the `defaultsups` option:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[defaultsups]{newpxtext}

\begin{document}
No error at footnote number here.\footnote{No error.}
\end{document}
```